# Chartjs with PHP problem (Unexpected token)

Tags: php, charts, chart.js

I have the code given below

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["A1", "B1", "C1"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '',
                datasets:[
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_A1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mesin where LokasiMesin='A1'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_A1);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_B1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mesin where LokasiMesin='B1'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_B1);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_C1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mesin where LokasiMesin='C1'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_C1);
                    ?>,
                    backgroundColor: [ <!-- Error on here -->
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1;
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

The error on browser console is "Unexpected token: " (marked on code line), But when I follow the documentation of Chart.js, the documentation is likely the same as what I am doing.

Here's the picture:

[image]

Any help to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some error on your datasets bracket

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["A1", "B1", "C1"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '',
                datasets:[
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_A1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mesin where LokasiMesin='A1'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_A1);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_B1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mesin where LokasiMesin='B1'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_B1);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_C1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mesin where LokasiMesin='C1'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_C1);
                    ?>], <!-- Bracket here-->
                    backgroundColor: [ 
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1;
            }]
        }
```